# Tridion 2011/2013 Publishing Queue Log - show all transactions, including failed

Tags: 2011, 2013, publishing, 2013-sp1, publishtransaction

Can I get the Publishing Queue Log to show all publishing transactions, including instances where the transactions failed multiple times & then succeeded?  It seems like  the Queue only shows one failure, not all of them.  Is this the case?  I'd like a complete list of all failures, not just one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The publishing queue will indeed only show the last transaction with a given state. If you have 10 failed publishing transactions, the queue will only show the last one, as we assume that the previous 9 are irrelevant to you.

As of 2013 SP1 Tridion actually keeps all the data - this was not the case before, in the database we would actually delete "irrelevant" transactions. Using TOM.NET or the CoreService you can get all the transaction history, but in the UI we still hide older transactions.

**UPDATE** This assumption I made here is incorrect, 2013 SP1 kept publishing history for deleted items (for bundle support) but not the history of all publishing for any given item/target combination.

Comment: Hi Nuno  is there a way we can get the  details of item removed from publishing queue using tridion 2013 SP1. or do we still need to write custom event system to store the information of the items manually removed from the publishing queue. Please calrify.

Comment: No idea if we keep a transaction that we never executed. You may want to ask that as a normal question so that others see it too